# c# assign a button custom location on FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` on which I have some `Buttons` ordered vertically (the panel ordered automatically just the way I wanted). But now I want to place another `button1` but with a custom location (at the top right corner of `FlowLayoutPanel`). So far I tried `button1.Location = new Point(x,y);` but the `button1` is still placed in order. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position a control in your desired location you're using a wrong container. `FlowLayouPanel` as name suggests it arranges its children in a flow manner.

Either use simple `Panel` or create a custom [LayoutEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To answer your another question: To place buttons vertically you can do this.

```
Point location = Point.Empty;
foreach (Button button in buttons)
{
    button.Location = location;
    location.Y += button.Height;
    location.Y += 10;//Add some space
}
```

Another approach is to use descendant of `FlowLayoutPanel` and override the `OnLayout` method like this.

```
public class MyFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        base.OnLayout(levent);

        var button = flowLayout.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (button != null)
            button.Location = new Point(flowLayout.Width - button.Width, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can you tell me how to place my buttons in vertical order on a simple panel? That would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: @user3677210 You can set the [`FlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [`TopDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will work like this http://www.dotnetperls.com/flow.png.

Comment: @famousgarkin Read the question again, I guess OP is aware of that, problem is OP needs to add a button in custom location. That's what I understood.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Agreed, in the case it's still related to custom location you gave the answer.

Comment: Heres what my FLPanel looks like: http://oi58.tinypic.com/4lgeur.jpg
I want the button (not the radiobuttons) to be on the top of the right corner instead of left. Thanks

Comment: @user3677210 Check the updated answer, that should help.